# How to write a custom function to extract information from a specific row/Series of dataframe if categorical information is provided?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, series

I want to write a function that can show me "Account Name" based on the country I write. The final output should look like this

write_country("United States")
So it will provide all "Account Name" which are from United States.

The data is given below

```
Rank    Account username    Account Name    Followers (millions)    Occupation  Country
0   1   @BarackObama    Barack Obama    132.0   44th President of the United States of America  United States
1   2   @justinbieber   Justin Bieber   114.2   Musician    Canada
2   3   @katyperry  Katy Perry  108.8   Musician    United States

my code is 
entity=df.groupby([ "Country"])
b=df["Account Name"]
for items in zip(entity,b):
    print(items)
```

When I add this code in function, it give me error that boolean operators are not iterable.

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: I have edited the code with my attempt

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option:

```
import pandas as pd


def write_country(country):

    return df[df['Country'].isin([country])][["Account Name", 'Country']]


df = pd.DataFrame({'Rank': [1, 2, 3], 'Account username': ['@BarackObama', '@justinbieber', '@katyperry'],
                'Account Name': ['Barack Obama', 'Justin Bieber', 'Katy Perry'],
                'Followers (millions)': [132.0, 114.2, 108.8],
                'Occupation': ['44th President of the United States of America', 'Musician', 'Musician'],
                'Country': ['United States', 'Canada', 'United States']})

account_name =  write_country('United States')
print(account_name)
```